# In Rails, how should we get parameters in java scripts？

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, parameters

When I use the code

```
 <%= render 'chart', width:100 %>
```

I can get the width value in the page, like  <%= width %>

But if I want to get the width value in java script in the same page, I really have no idea.
So my pending solution is hiding the value in the div, then use the $('div').text() to retrieve the value.

So I just want to know if we have any other way to get the parameters passed in rails by java script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly output the value in the javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var width = <%= width %>;
</script>
```

The code in Ruby/Rails will be interpreted *during* the rendering, and will output the (ruby) variable `width` inside the generated HTML.