# redirect_to anchor changes url but not page rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have integrated a html template in my rails app. It's actually a single page template but uses anchors to render different sections as pages. Like,

```
localhost:3000/#home
localhost:3000/#email
```

renders those anchors with a transition-to-different-page effect. 
Now, I have this in my controller,

```
 if @message.valid?
      NotificationsMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(root_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
 else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      redirect_to root_path(anchor: 'email')
 end
```

In the else portion, after the redirect the url in browser does change to `localhost:3000/#email` but it still shows the `localhost:3000/#home` anchor portion. After actually clicking on the link `localhost:3000/#email` in my navbar, changes the home page and renders the `email` anchor.

DevTools and Firebug are not showing any error in console though. What's the problem?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using anchor for your pages? Rails must simply be adding the anchor, but does not capture the hash change and thus, does not render the page. When you click on the link, it does capture the change.

Comment: @JustinD. : Click on this link having an anchor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189610/in-rails-how-should-we-get-parameters-in-java-scripts/18189652?noredirect=1#comment26672398_18189652 Don't you see your browser scrolling down to the comment defined in the anchor? It is also used in Client side for calling JS function, useful when working with Backbone / Angular.JS, etc.

Comment: @MrYoshiji, I know why and how are used anchor links. I even have an app developed with SammyJs (uses hash change to route). My question was more why would you do that in a Rails app it looks to me you are loading a new page.

Comment: I believe that the problem is not in the Rails part of the application - it does set the URL correctly after all. Look at your HTML template.